# Automatizar script colab

Tags: python

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de automatizar un script de colab, lo que pasa es que me conecto directamente a una base de datos de Drive y se hizo la conexión desde colab, pero necesito que esa tarea se ejecute diariamente. ¿Alguna idea de cómo se puede realizar?

Comment: Crea un script en tu pc que se conecte a tu drive, descargue el archivo y lo ejecute como un servicio

Comment: Podrías explicarme un poco más la verdad no he generado el script local porque no sé como hacer la conexión al drive y no entiendo como se ejecutaría como servicio